# Getting data from repo in Rest API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest

When I try to fetch my data from the repository and try to console.log the data, the array appears to be empty. The data repo looks like this:

[image]

Code of server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
// importing data
import data from './my-app/src/backend/products'

//initiate express server
const app = express()

//define path as end point
app.get('/', (req,res)=> {

    res.send(data)
})

app.get('/api/products', (req,res)=> {
    res.send(data)
})

//listen to server
app.listen(5000,()=> {
    console.log('server is alive and stereo! -Hannah Baker')
} )
```

code of the product card where i want to fetch data:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {Library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {faShoppingBasket} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import axios from 'axios'


function Product(props){
    //default value is an array, because we've got data in an array 
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        //we define a function
         const fetchData = async ()=>{
             //get the results and place them in the data variable
             const {data} = await axios.get("/")
             //set state to data
             setProducts(data)
         }
         fetchData()
    }, [])

    function HandleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert('added to cart !')
        
    }

 console.log(products)
   
    return(
        
           <ul className="products">
               
            {products.map(product=> (
                
            <li key={product.id} className="product">
             <Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><div className="img" style={{background: `url(${product.img})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}></div></Link>
                   {/* LOOK OUT FOR TYPOS IN ROUTIING  dont put':' after /, this only applies
                   when routing because the ": " implies for a parameter
                   In this case you can directly access product.id  */}
               <Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link> 
                <p> <small>€</small>{product.price}</p>
                <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
                <button>Add to cart</button> 
                </form>
                
                </li> 
                )
                
                )}
   
                 </ul>
       
    )
}
export default Product
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstood axios requests. You can use "/" only after you defined the base URL, and if you haven't defined the base URL you need to use the full link "localhost:5000/". To define the base URL create an instance.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:5000/'
});
```

Then use it as:

```
const {data} = await instance.get("/")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NevecEx . Have you also got the solution for the product properties i want to access? I am trying to acces the .id, .name, etc. But they are undefined. Could it be because of the way my products repo is being displayed in javscript and not in json ?

Comment: No, the issue is that react is trying to load the data before you requested it. Change {products.map(product=> ( to {products != [] && products.map(product=> (

Comment: @Crazyfrog You need to check if the products have been loaded, check my previous comment.

Comment: i did that, but had no success

Answer (score 0):

Use **res.json** instead **res.send**

```
var quotes = [
  { author : 'Audrey Hepburn', text : "Nothing is impossible, the word itself says 'I'm possible'!"},
  { author : 'Walt Disney', text : "You may not realize it when it happens, but a kick in the teeth may be the best thing in the world for you"}
];

app.get('/quotes', function(req, res) {
  res.json(quotes);
});
```

Also if your file is  valid json string, you must need to convert to an object with classic

```
JSON.parse()
```

## Advice

Before consume your http endpoint (express api) try to test it using some of the following clients to ensure that is working and returns a valid json ( content-type:application/json ):

- postman
- curl
- soapui
- etc

## Samples

- https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/blob/master/03-cors-companies.js

Comment: app.get('/', (req,res)=> {
    const ParsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    res.send(ParsedData)
})

Comment: I did that, but i still get the same results. And i still get an empty array when console.logging the data

Comment: Could you try with this https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/blob/master/03-cors-companies.js ?? Clone it and verify if it works. Just replace 42 line with your data